# Can't apply style to ScrollViewer in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, styles, scrollviewer

ScrollViewer is a good stuff to cooperate with WrapPanel because when there are content overflow, we can use ScrollViewer to show the hidden one.
In my current project, I used WrapPanel as container, ScrollViewer as the component to display  the hidden parts. but Now I get a problem when setting style to the scrollviewer, the problem is : however I set the style to scrollviewer, It won't change a bit. here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                            Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFE9EEF4"
                            Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"
                            Minimum="0"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding
                                ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Width="18"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Height="18"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                            Margin="-1,0,-1,-1"
                            Minimum="0"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding
                                ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the place I apply the style:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" x:Name="sclViewer"
    Style="{StaticResource CustomScrollViewerStyle}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0">
    <toolkit:WrapPanel
        Width="{Binding ElementName=sclViewer, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}">
        <uc:UserCPage x:Name="commonUC1" Title="test" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I　am new to silverlight, I have checked my code a lot but can't find what the reason caused this. Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors or anything?

Comment: @ChrisW. No, No errors found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this question solved by using Silverlight spy, You can google it.
I used this tool to reflect my app and got all the structure of the scrollviewer, I　copied the xaml structure out and changed some styles and then make it into resource dictionary, finally all is ok for me.